# How to update a row in room? (please read first)

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

So I observe my room db in recyclerview via viewmodel. To update a row I call update method on repository object in activity. Am I doing it right? Because this is what I have seen in tutorials. My question is if we are using repository object for update, create and viewmodel to read data, whats the use case for setdata and postdata methods of livedata? Also how to update an entire table(overwrite)?

Observing

```
noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, Observer<List<Note>> { notes ->
            notes?.let {
                notesList = notes as ArrayList<Note>
                notesAdapter = NotesAdapter(notes, this@MainActivity)
                recyclerView.adapter = notesAdapter
                notesAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })
```

Updating

```
NoteDatabase.getInstance(this@MainActivity).noteDao().updateNote(
                notechecked.also { it.done = value }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. This is exactly how your'e supposed to observe and update rows in `Room`.

The use case for `setData` and `postData` methods of `LiveData` are.. well.. to update the LiveData object.

For example, `Room` uses `postData()` to update the `LiveData` object it initially returned (when you called `getAllNotes()`), whenever you update your DB in a way that affects your `LiveData` object.

Because `Room` calls `postData()` for you, you don't need to.

But, if you were to hold some value directly in your `viewmodel` (rather than in `Room`), inside a `LiveData` object, and you'd want to change it when the user clicks something in your view, you'd have to call `setData/postData` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Well explained.

Comment: Glad i could help! please accept the answer so other people can find it more easily